# What is the fastest, most efficient way to copy from one network location to another?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am using this line from my local machine...

```
CopyItem -Path \\comp1.a\c$\folder\ -Destination \\comp2.b\c$\folder\ -Recurse
```

and it's taking orders of magnitude longer than if I remote into comp2.b and xcopy. I am a PS noob (since yesterday!) but I think this is somehow passing through my machine or going around our network somehow unnecessarily. Is there another cmd-let or parameter that is more efficient?

Oh... and while I've got you. Do y'all professional PS people use the named parameters like that or just positional?

Comment: To answer your last question, it just doesn't matter so long as it works :)

Comment: I prefer positional parameters and use named parameters when I have to. Then again, I'm not a professional PS person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the most efficient way for folder synchronization over a network is [`robocopy`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Check this bad boy out:
[PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx)

The Ps doesn't stand for PowerShell. This is part of the PsTools package that Sysinternals sold out to Microsoft. They are free and amazing. With PsExec, you could connect remotely to one of the machines and invoke the copy command.